# How to push latest docker image to docker hub?

Tags: docker

I'm tagging my docker image as `foo/foo:latest`

When there's single image, it's fine to do `docker push`

But since I'm always tagging them as `foo/foo:latest`, I wonder if it's possible to upload not the latest built image.

When you tag an image, does the previous image loses the tag if it had the same tag?

Comment: The `tag` can only be associated with a single `image` - i.e. today's `image:latest` tag will crush yesterday's `image:latest` image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single image can be associated with multiple tags. i.e If you try to remove an image using the `docker image rm` only metadata is removed if the image is associated with multiple tags.

But a `tag` can be associated with only a single image. Performing a `docker push` will overwrite the existing image in the repository.

Comment: This is most likely accurate in the context of the OP's question. However there are multi architecture manifests that use one tag to point to a list of images, one per architecture.

Comment: Yes, you are right @BMitch. I was referring in terms of OPs context. Please feel free to add more details to the existing answer